# And Next? v.s. What's Next?

Tags: word-choice, differences

I am debating between using "And Next?" and "What's Next?". I understand that they are not comparable. However, I want to ask for your feedback on the two terms.

Let me describe in what context I am using it. This is going to be a title for a three-step model that I am developing. The last step of the model is about actions or help etc.

Which one do you think is most suitable to use? "What's Next?" or "And Next?"

I have a feeling that "And Next?" implies there should be something next and what is it, while "What's Next?" is more of a neutral position.

Comment: We need more context.  Please provide the rest of your verbiage.

Comment: You left out who is your audience. Techies? Can you use the one word 'Next'?

Comment: ...and now, for something completely different...

Comment: Thanks all, for more context, this is the model I am talking about: http://the.simplecoachingmodel.com I am debating on the last part of the model what to name.

Comment: Based on your slides: "Other Approaches.'

Answer (score 1):

"And Next?" sounds funny to my ears. It doesn't seem grammatically correct.

If you thought "What's Next?" doesn't fit in your case then you're probably right because it has the sound of a broader context kind of like asking "What's the next big thing in your life?" or "What's next after colonizing Mars?".

Perhaps you can consider titling your model "And **Then**?".

Comment: Thanks @Kumar I think "And Then?" is a good choice as well. I agree with you on the funny part.